# Android - can't go back to mainActivity after starting a different app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Okay, I think I'm missing something here but can't seem to find a way around it :\
So this is my scenario, I have two apps, A and B. A Opens a B with the following intent:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
Intent n = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(currAppInfo.getName());
n.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(n);
```

(currAppInfo is a custom object and getName returns the package name.)

Anyway, B is installing APKs. A receives the package installed broadcast and should be now moved back to front, how ever if I'm starting app A with an intent

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
serviceIntent.setClass(context, MainActivity.class);
serviceIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(serviceIntent);
```

Instead of seeing A's mainActivity screen all I see is B's main activity screen.
Why is that? Is it the way I open the apps with the intents or am I missing something more basic here?

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong. You launch B from A. When B finished installing a APK, it sends the broadcast and A receive it and bring it to foreground. And the problem is the A cannot appear on top.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that after the intent is sent B is becoming on top instead of A.